# Convert a json value to column values in oracle sql select query

Tags: sql, json, oracle

I have a table in oracle and one of the column is holding a json data like below

Table name : EMPLOYEE_DETAIL

| ID | JSON_DATA |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"Name":"Ram", "Email":"Ram@gmail.com","Age":34} |

Here, the JSON is not nested and all are in key value pair only. Also the key can be dynamic ,meaning next json set of data will be having totally different column names.

I need to write a select query which will convert this json into column value format as response in oracle sql. My query will select only one single ID so that no multiple column with different JSON information will not be available.

For example , the above JSON will be convert to :

| ID | Name | Email | Age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ram | Ram@gmail.com | 34 |

Comment: A similar question has been asked in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56484042/how-to-convert-json-format-oracle-table-row-values-into-multiple-relational-colu) but I can't flag this as duplicate because it has not a valid answer. Caius gave the link and I think that link can be helpful too. > https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/json.htm#ADXDB6371